# Maximize size of bucket such that product is not cube

Tags: c++, algorithm

In a given sequence of non- negative numbers,we have to put some numbers in a bucket, such that the product of any two distinct elements in bucket is not a cube and numbers in bucket is maximum. Find the maximum number of elements in bucket.

Is there any algorithm to do such question?

Comment: You could use A*

Comment: @eerorika,sorry I am not getting.

Comment: You asked for an algorithm, I told you the name of an algorithm that can solve the problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2A_search_algorithm

Comment: This algorithm is new to me. Can anyone tell me the logic of this question. please

Comment: @BINDUROY The algorithm is well known, it's explained in the linked article, and no doubt in many other sites on the internet. Could you not just take the time to read about it and if you don't understand anything ask again. This isn't a tutorial site. It's a site for specific questions about programming.

Comment: I would do that way: add all numbers ine bucket and then start removing following some logic.

Comment: How big are the numbers?

Comment: @BessieTheCow it is of order 10^10.

Comment: @Daniel which logic u are talking about?

Comment: Not sure, maybe check each pair product and if they make a cube, remove the smallest (but paying attention to the element you remove, because if you remove an element `a` that forms a cube with `b`, if you ever remove `b`, maybe you can restore `a`).

Comment: Can anyone help me with proper logic

Answer (score 2):

for any two positive integers *m* and *n*, *m*⋅*n* is a cube iff there are positive integers *a* and *b* such that:

- (*m = a* and *n = a²*), or
- (*m = a²b* and *n = ab²*), or
- (*m = a³* and *n = b³*)

If you'll factor all inputs, you can check which pairs cannot be added together.

There are several other methods to check if a number is a perfect cube:

1. Take the cube root from a value. Then round that outcome to get its integer value. Next, raise that rounded value to the third power. When that outcome matches the original number, that number is a perfect cube. (Note that this method subjects to rounding error for large integers). See [here](https://kodify.net/python/math/perfect-cube/).
2. The digital root of a perfect cube is 1, 8, or 9 (0). See [here](http://burningmath.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-know-or-check-if-number-is.html).
3. Pre-construct a list of all the cubes in a given range. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perfect-cubes-range/).
4. Based on its binary representation (excellent for large integers): See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3570545/what-are-the-different-ways-to-check-if-a-number-is-perfect-cube)

Next, you'll need to find the maximum cardinality subset that can be put together in the bucket.

You can build a graph, where each node represents an input number, and there is an edge between two nodes if the two numbers can be added together. Now, find a [Maximum Clique](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X01002906) (the size of a maximum clique is called the [Clique Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CliqueNumber.html) of the graph).

Equivalently, you can add an edge between two nodes if the two numbers ***cannot*** be added together. Now, find a [Maximum Independent Vertex Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs).